# asp.net forms authentication script

Tags: asp.net

I need the script to create ASPNETDB.MDF of Forms Authentication. 
I don't have Management Studio, without that is there any way to get the create script of all tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [SQL Registration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx).